# R: dataframe new column using multiple if conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains phone numbers in different formats, I'm trying to clean wrongly formatted numbers and unify the format by creating a new column.
phone numbers exist in 3 columns: CountryCode, AreaCode, MobileNumber.
I've written the following code to create a new column based on multiple if conditions:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mutate(data, Number = 
                 if(nchar(data$MobileNumber >= 12))
                             {paste("+", data$MobileNumber)
                   } else if (nchar(data$MobileNumber >= 9))
                            {paste("+", data$CountryCode, data$MobileNumber)
                   } else if (data$CountryCode == data$AreaCode)
                            {paste("+", data$CountryCode, data$MobileNumber)
                   } else   (paste("+", data$CountryCode, data$AreaCode, data$MobileNumber)))
```

it acts based on the condition of the first row only, giving the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (nchar(data$MobileNumber >= 12)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've also tried to create 3 vectors for CountryCode, AreaCode, MobileNumber then to create a function that takes the 3 vectors as input and the correctly formatted number as output using if conditions and for loop but also wasn't successful.

```
# x is number y is country code z is area code n is the output
x <- data$MobileNumber
y <- as.character(data$CountryCode)
z <- data$AreaCode

#cleaning function
out <- vector("character", nrow(data))
CleanNum <- function(x, y, z) 
  { for(i in 1:length(x))
       { if(nchar(x[i] >= 12))      {n[i] <- paste("+", x[i])
       } else if (nchar(x[i] >= 9)) {n[i] <- paste("+", y[i], x[i])
       } else if (y[i] == z[i])     {n[i] <- paste("+", y[i], x[i])
       } else                       (n[i] <- paste("+", y[i], z[i], x[i])) 
            out[i] <- n[i]    }}

Num_vec <- CleanNum(x, y, z)
```

I've a little experience in R and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See `ifelse` for vectorized conditions. Also, you probably meant to close the `nchar` bracket before `>= 12` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in `base R` using `vapply`

```
data$Number <- vapply(1:nrow(data),function (k) {
  if(nchar(data$MobileNumber[k]) >= 12) return(paste("+", data$MobileNumber[k]))
  if(nchar(data$MobileNumber[k]) >= 9) return(paste("+", data$CountryCode[k], data$MobileNumber[k]))
  if (data$CountryCode[k] == data$AreaCode[k]) return(paste("+", data$CountryCode[k], data$MobileNumber[k]))
  paste("+", data$CountryCode[k], data$AreaCode[k], data$MobileNumber[k]))
}, character(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that you can apply through mutate as in your first example.

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(CountryCode = CountryCode %>%
               as.character(),
           Number = case_when(
               MobileNumber %>%
                   nchar() >= 12 ~ paste("+", 
                                         MobileNumber),
               MobileNumber %>% 
                   nchar() >= 9 ~ paste("+", 
                                        CountryCode,
                                        MobileNumber),
               CountryCode == AreaCode ~ paste("+",
                                               CountryCode,
                                               MobileNumber),
               TRUE ~ paste("+",
                            CountryCode,
                            AreaCode,
                            MobileNumber)
         )
)
```

This solution allows you to keep working with the existing data.frame through just adding another column.